# javascript summary function

Tags: javascript, function, summary

im trying to make a small name summary function depending on the size of the elements container, here's what I have;

```
function shorten_text(str, size){
    size = size.match( /[0-9]*/ );
    var endValue = Math.floor( Number(size) / 10 );
    var number;
    var newStr;
    for ( number = 0; number <= endValue; number++ ) {
        if( str[number].length != 0 ) {
            newStr += str[number];
        }
    }   
    return newStr + '...';

}
shorten_text('Phil Jackson', '94px');
// output should be 'Phil Jack...'
```

What I seem to get is undefinedundef...
can anyone see where I am going wrong?

EDIT:

revised code based on comments below for anyone who is googling for such function:

```
function shorten_text(str, size){
    size = parseInt(size);
    var endValue = Math.floor(size / 10);
    if( str.length > endValue ) {
        return str.substring(0, endValue) + '...';
    }else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

SCREEN SHOT:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you assuming that each character is one pixel wide? How does this work?

Comment: I have added screenshot to show.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get how does adding 1 character for each pixel of the width works for you, as each character has variable width that is surely more than 1 pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your `newStr` variable with an empty string, otherwise that variable will contain the `undefined` value, which will be converted to string when  you concatenate, e.g.:

```
var test; // at this moment the variable contains the undefined value
test += 'foo';
// now test contains "undefinedfoo"
```

In your function:

```
function shorten_text(str, size){
    size = size.match( /[0-9]*/ );
    var endValue = Math.floor( Number(size) / 10 );
    var number;
    var newStr = '';
    for ( number = 0; number <= endValue; number++ ) {
        if( str[number].length != 0 ) {
            newStr += str[number];
        }
    }   
    return newStr + '...';
}

shorten_text('Phil Jackson', '94px'); //  outputs "Phil Jacks..."
```

A few comments:

- You don't need to call `Number(size)`, since the division operator makes type coercion. implicitly
- You could use the `substring` method to get a portion of your original string.
- Accessing characters of a string with the square bracket property accessor may not be supported by some implementations, you can use the standard `charAt` method (`str.charAt(i)`)

Another approach to do the same:

```
function shorten_text(str, size){
    var endValue = Math.floor(parseInt(size) / 10);
    return str.substring(0, endValue) + '...';
}

shorten_text('Phil Jackson', '94px'); //  outputs "Phil Jack..." as expected
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very informative. I m here to learn! ( and works like a charm )

Comment: tuche, does save time and space!

Comment: The shorter shorten_text outputs a slightly different answer ('Jack' instead of 'Jacks') -- needs a "+1" if you want the same. I'm going to delete my own now-redundant answer.

Comment: @Darius: Yes I noted this, but the OP expects to get 'Phil Jack...' (look the comment on the question)